# ::PostMessage doesn't work when I am tabbed in to another program

Tags: c++, mfc

In our Program we have a Dialog from a separate dll open to display infomation. I need to close this dialog when our system timer causes the system to lock.

I send information to the dll by registering a system message in both my MainFrm and EditDisplayDll

> SYSTEMLOCK = RegisterWindowMessage("SystemLock");

When I sent the message via

> ::PostMessage(GetActiveWindow()->m_hWnd,SYSTEMLOCK,0,0);

The message correctly sends to my EditDisplayDll and closes the dialog when the system locks; however, if I alt tab while waiting for the timeout and use another program(firefox, outlook, etc.) the message never correctly calls to the EditDisplayDll. The `MainFrm` and other windows inside of the `MainFrm` correctly lockout and hide themselves in either case.

I have tried also using HWND_BROADCAST with `PostMessage` and `SendNotifyMessage`. I have also tried to use `FindWindow()` and `FindWindowEx()` to specifically call the EditDisplayDll.

I cannot use something like `GetDlgItem()` because my `MainFrm.cpp` doesn't have access to this dll.

My decision to use `GetActiveWindow()` was because I believe it looks to windows specific to my program no matter what window I am in as seen in the imagery in [Foreground Vs Active window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940346/foreground-vs-active-window)

Finally, my question is, is there a way to call all Windows in my program no matter what program I am currently in or is there another way I could get access to the specific IDD of the EditDisplayDll in order to send the `SYSTEMLOCK` message to it?

Comment: Whats the problem you face to find the window handle using FindWindow() ?

Comment: The build compiles when I try to use `FindWindow()` but it never correctly finds the EditDisplayDll so the message never sends.

Comment: How are you calling FindWindow ?

Comment: One way I tried was `CWnd *cWndED = FindWindow(_T("EditDisplay"),_T("EditDisplay"));
   HWND hwnd = (HWND)cWndED;
   ::PostMessage(hwnd,SYSTEMLOCK,0,0);'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> CWnd *cWndED = FindWindow(_T("EditDisplay"),_T("EditDisplay"));  HWND
>   hwnd = (HWND)cWndED;

You should use win32 API ::FindWindow with proper class, window name. And do not cast CWnd pointer to HWND. Your code should look like:

```
HWND hWnd = ::FindWindow(_T("ProperClass"), _T("ProperNmae"));
if (hWnd != NULL)
{
  ::PostMessage(hWnd, YOUR_MESSAGE, ....);
}
```

I will suggest you to find your Dll window class and name using Spy++ and then try to find that using above method. Remember it's always better to use native API for this kind of tasks.

Comment: I'll look in to Spy++ and see if I can implement the changes you have suggested when I return to work tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

[`FindWindow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms633499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is a good solution if you know both, name of the window and the element.
If you want to get the `HWND` of your window - no element inside the window -, you can pass as first parameter `NULL`.

```
::FindWindow(NULL, _T("WindowName"));
```

Back to your code: If you are lucky your [`PostMessage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) does nothing, otherwise the active window may catch your message. Who knows how/if it is handled in the active window ? Use the [`PostMessage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) if you have a valid [`IsWindow(HWND)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms633528%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) from [`FindWindow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms633499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [`FindWindowEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633500%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
In case you want a `CWnd` from your `HWND` take a look at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e547yfza%28v=vs.120%29.aspx). (The call may be slow)

```
HWND hWnd = ::FindWindow(_T("ClassName"), _T("WindowName"));
if (hWnd && IsWindow(hWnd))
{
    ::PostMessage(hWnd, MESSAGE_TO_BE_SEND, lParam_or_Flags);
}
```

Comment: I don't know why you are suggesting OP to use nulltptr as first parameter. It should be NULL in windows terminology to find a window with only title name. And moreover in microsoft enviroment its always preferrable to use NULL as a notation.