# Combine two windows so that they have single input focus?

Tags: delphi, winapi

Is it possible to combine two windows (Forms) so that they have single input focus, and one form don't become inactive when switching to another form? Focus here (and only here) is an Active or Foreground state of Win API, not the cursor.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are looking to achieve, so please [read answers of this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940346/foreground-vs-active-window). Then reformulate your question, e.g. to explain why you are asking.

Comment: I use parent form, and control form of different application using `SetParent`. So, if a "child" form of different application activates, the "parent" deactivates. It is possible to return it manually, but some items (popup menus will disappear), for example. In **this** question I asked not exactly that, but that's "I'm looking to achieve".

Comment: Can work without returning focus, but want to parent window not become inactive and changed their header, and Alt-Tab. Did I mentioned Alt-Tab?

Comment: As far as I know, only the *Foreground application* can have an *Active window*. The foreground application / active window is the one that receives input events (e.g. keyboard events). Other applications also have active windows, but they do not receive input events (as they are not foreground applications). When focus is taken away from a window, any currently open menu of that window, is closed. So, it seems the answer is *not possible*.

Comment: you mean like a tool window?

Comment: @jsmith "*I use parent form, and control form of different application using `SetParent`.*" - [that will not work out well](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130412-00/?p=4683).

Comment: @whosrdaddy like MDI child window, but without header and restore/minimize capability. In a single process, parent and child window can have like-a-single focus.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no! You can't have focus on multiple windows at the same time - that's the way how Windows is designed.

There are still some ways for your application(s) to react to input (keyboard, mouse...) even if your application does not have focus.

If you only need to react to a keystroke you can [register a global hotkey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerhotkey) with your application and then handle what happens when that specific hotkey is pressed, even when your application is not active.

But if you need to react to every keyboard or mouse input then you will have to register [system-wide hooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/about-hooks) accordingly. The main advantage of hooks is that you will be able to detect keyboard and mouse events even before the active application does and thus, if needed, also intercept them entirely so that other applications won't receive them at all/anymore.

But beware that when implementing hooks incorrectly you could cause havoc to the computer since you are working on a low level approach that could even lead to system crashes if not done correctly.

Comment: i'm just translating wm_keydown messages from parent to child without hooks (and some messages to prevent loops)

Comment: A misbehaving input hook can render the system unusable, but it cannot cause the system to crash.

Comment: how MDI windows can be both active (parent and child)? at least it shows header color of both as active. is there a way to "emulate" MDI windows through different applications?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Active Window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-features#active-window) Document:

> **An active window is the top-level window of the application with which the user is currently working.** To allow the user to easily
> identify the active window, the system places it at the top of the
> z-order and changes the color of its title bar and border to the
> system-defined active window colors. **Only a top-level window can be
> an active window. When the user is working with a child window, the
> system activates the top-level parent window associated with the child
> window.**
>
> **Only one top-level window in the system is active at a time.**

The MDI windows also has only one active window.

To create a window like MDI(which will show header color of both as active), you could try to add the `WS_CHILD` style to the child window.

If you also want to realize that one thread shares its input state with another thread, you can try [`AttachThreadInput`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-attachthreadinput).